# DNN-6 Compiling Issue

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

In our DNN system when someone tries to edit a wiki topic , it seems like compiler going crazy.When i check the HTML tab , both codes are seems same , no difference . Our version is 6.x

Broken Image
[image: Broken_Image]

Working Image
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I get no idea of what your question is. Beside this, DNN 6 is very old and has a lot of security issues in the meantime. You should consider upgrading to the latest version (which can be a challenge).

Comment: My problem is , sometimes DNN structure squezes texts which makes a terrible look. Anyway i see that i must upgrade our DNN . Do you know any consultation company which can help me with this proccess ? Because we have around 40-50 modules or applications are deeply attached to our current DNN.